# Adding strings from python to text file and then verify lines in while loop

Tags: python-3.7

I'm new to coding and still learning about Python.
I have a task where I have to upload lines from Python to a text file and then verify the lines later in the code e.g. I have to input user names and user passwords and add to the text file as [user_name, user_pass].
My problem is that when I try to verify the line one of 2 things happen. After I added a split function for the line e.g. verified_user, verified_password = line.split(", ") it runs into an error stating that I do not have enough values for the request made e.g 2 expected, 1 made. If I change the split input and it does run, the verification loop states that my inputs does not match any lines in the string.

Every thing works if I add the information to the text file only. But the moment I add via the appendix action in Python it no longer works.

this is what I have so far:

```
user_list = []
all_names_entered = "no"

while all_names_entered == "no":

   user_name = input("Enter user name: ")
   user_pass = input("Enter password: ")
   user_list.append(user_name + ", " + user_pass)

    while True:
    all_names_entered = input("All users entered?: ")
      if all_names_entered in ['yes','no']:
        break
     else:
        print( 'please answer with yes or no' )
for items in user_list:
with open('user.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(f"{user_name}, {user_pass}\n")
print (user_list)

file.close()
```

the next block reads as follow:

```
   user_file = open("user.txt", "r+")
   login = False

while login == False:
   username = input("Enter user name: ")
   password = input("Enter user password: ")

for line in user_file:
    other = line.strip()
    valid_user, valid_password = line.split(", ")
if username == valid_user and password == valid_password:
    login = True
    print ("You have successfully logged in")
    break
else:
    print("You have entered incorrect detail. Please try again")

user_file.seek(0)
    
user_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, indentation is important in Python.
- Secondly, you're supposed to loop if user enters 'no'.
- Utilize the `item` that's initialized in each `for` loop.
- You initialized `other` but it was never consumed.

Following is code for writing into file:

```
user_list = []
all_names_entered = "no"

while all_names_entered == "no":
    user_name = input("Enter user name: ")
    user_pass = input("Enter password: ")
    user_list.append(user_name + ", " + user_pass)
    query_all_names_entered = True
    while query_all_names_entered:
        all_names_entered = input("All users entered?: ")
        if all_names_entered == 'yes':
            query_all_names_entered = False
            break
        elif all_names_entered == 'no':
            query_all_names_entered = False
            continue
        else:
            print('Please answer with yes or no')
            all_names_entered = "no"
with open('user.txt', 'a') as file:
    for item in user_list:
        file.write(f"{item}\n")
print (user_list)

file.close()
```

And following is for reading file to log in:

```
user_file = open("user.txt", "r+")
login = False
lines = user_file.readlines()

while login == False:
    username = input("Enter user name: ")
    password = input("Enter user password: ")

    for line in lines:
        valid_user, valid_password = line.strip().split(", ")
        if username == valid_user and password == valid_password:
            login = True
            print ("You have successfully logged in")
            break
    if login == False: print ("You have entered incorrect detail. Please try again")

user_file.close()
```